# SSRS report stuck on Loading but ExecutionLog says otherwise

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssrs

[image: Loading]

I have a report that is stuck on loading in the reporting server portal (it's been over a day). However when i check the ExecutionLog...

```
select * from ExecutionLog3 
WHERE UserName = 'SOMEREPORTSERVER\SomeName'
AND ExecutionID = 'cbk0hdnpzrspg5qpkvqxubyn'
order by TimeStart desc
```

...it says that the status is 'rsSuccess'. [image: Results]

Here is the AdditionalInfo XML which might help... The query took about 1 minute to run which is how long it took to run in SSMS. Rendering seems pretty fair with the amount of data returned so I am not sure what's going on.

I made sure that Interactive Sizing is standard 8.5 x 11 so that it can show at least some data while processing the other pages but that did not help.

```
<AdditionalInfo>
  <ProcessingEngine>2</ProcessingEngine>
  <ScalabilityTime>
    <Pagination>0</Pagination>
    <Processing>0</Processing>
  </ScalabilityTime>
  <EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
    <Pagination>263471</Pagination>
    <Processing>3795406</Processing>
  </EstimatedMemoryUsageKB>
  <DataExtension>
    <SQL>2</SQL>
  </DataExtension>
  <Connections>
    <Connection>
      <ConnectionOpenTime>24</ConnectionOpenTime>
      <DataSets>
        <DataSet>
          <Name>nocontacts</Name>
          <RowsRead>79650</RowsRead>
          <TotalTimeDataRetrieval>10297</TotalTimeDataRetrieval>
          <QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>0</QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>
          <ExecuteReaderTime>10225</ExecuteReaderTime>
          <DataReaderMappingTime>0</DataReaderMappingTime>
          <DisposeDataReaderTime>0</DisposeDataReaderTime>
        </DataSet>
      </DataSets>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
      <ConnectionOpenTime>30</ConnectionOpenTime>
      <DataSets>
        <DataSet>
          <Name>contacts</Name>
          <RowsRead>724715</RowsRead>
          <TotalTimeDataRetrieval>70893</TotalTimeDataRetrieval>
          <QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>0</QueryPrepareAndExecutionTime>
          <ExecuteReaderTime>26506</ExecuteReaderTime>
          <DataReaderMappingTime>0</DataReaderMappingTime>
          <DisposeDataReaderTime>0</DisposeDataReaderTime>
        </DataSet>
      </DataSets>
    </Connection>
  </Connections>
</AdditionalInfo>
```

Edit: SSRS - 14.0.807.134 / SSMS - 14.0.17177.0 / Browser - Chrome 
Edit: Trying IE - 11.309.16299.0 - I don't have the access to update report viewer settings.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512029.aspx

Comment: No errors for that specific report, only ProcessAborted ones that i stopped myself.

Comment: You should post the version of SQL Server / SSRS. Does this same behavior exist with multiple web browsers? Chrome gives me similar behavior and other weirdness, I usually have to use IE to get best behavior results with SSRS.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Any joy with IE? SSRS is so flaky in other browsers I tend to stick with IE for SSRS (and nothing else!).

Comment: I also found only certain versions of IE worked with certain versions of SSRS. You may need to fiddle with the Compatibility Settings to get the correct behaviour...

Comment: It's currently running, been about an hour now... I'll try playing with the IE Emulation Settings as i don't have access to the report viewer configs.

Comment: SSRS 2014 and IE 11? Could it be this? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3666/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/

Comment: I looked at the same article you did. I tried the fix at the IE level but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the browser will time out or otherwise not return a rendered report even though the process is still running in the background and ultimately succeeds.  The browser will likely not even tell you it failed, it will just keep spinning or return a blank page.  The logs are indicating "success" meaning the process itself did indeed run correctly, but the logs won't tell you if browser successfully returned a rendered report.  I've usually seen this happen around the 10 minute mark, regardless of the configuration of server or report level timeout settings.  Your Execution Log shows it as over 10 minutes, so this is the possible reason.  Also, the Execution Log returned a massive Byte Count (~353 MB), and this may also be a culprit.

There are a few possible solutions to this problem:

1. Limit the amount of data that will be rendered in browser using pagination.  The Data Retrieval & Processing time should stay the same, but the Rendering time will be reduced as it is only returning the first page, and will only render other pages when you navigate to those using the arrows.  Reflecting back on the aforementioned massive Byte Count, so somewhere along the way it may have broke the camel's back. 
   Once the data is processed, exporting to a static format, such as Excel or PDF, will also likely be successful & should throw an error if it failed, rather than it attempting to render the entire report in browser as HTML.
2. Deploy the report in the export format to a File Share using a Subscription.  This will allow the process to run in the background on the server and render it to a file directly.  If you are unable to schedule this on a regular interval, this may be a bit inconvenient for the user to request it from an admin and require that admin to manually deploy it.  However, I believe this is better than the report user rerunning the same report multiple times, resulting in concurrent executions, further compounding processing issues, affecting all users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.  My SSRS report is bound to a SQL stored proc.  After many attempts to run, i logged into SQL server, open the "Activity Monitor" and found several SUSPENDED threats.  I killed all threads and my report worked